# What's going on with this weird behavior when using | inside ()?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm working on a Regex pattern that's giving me a headache.
Upon narrowing down the problem, I've encountered an odd behavior that I don't understand:

The sub pattern that I wanted to use in the first place

```
\.(\d|\d\d)
```

doesn't give me a full match when I provide the test string ".20", only the partial match ".2". However when I flip it around

```
(\d|\d\d)\.
```

gives me the full match "20." when I provide the test string "20."
I don't understand where this opposing behavior comes from, that's pretty straight forward. Either . + 1 digit or . + 2 digits. I'm not using ^ nor $, as test string I've tried this with ".20" as it is or buried in some other text.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide the string `.20` to the regex `\.(\d|\d\d)`, the `\.` in the regex matches the `.` in the string. Then it tries to match the left side of `|` i.e., `\d` with `2` which is also successful. Since the left side of the `|` has been matched, It will not try to match the right side of `|`. Hence, we have the final match of `0.2`. If the regex was something like `\.(\d\d|\d)`, then on inputting `0.20`, you would have got the full match of `0.20`.

When you provide`20.` to the regex `(\d|\d\d)\.`, it first matches the left side of `|` i.e., `\d` with the number `2`. Since, the left side of `|` has been matched completely, it does not try to match the right side of `|`. Now, it tries to match `\.` with the digit `0` which fails, of course. Due to failure, backtracking takes place and now the right side of `|` i.e., `\d\d` is matched against `20` and then `\.` is matched against `.`. Hence, you get the full match `20.`

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense but I guess that's one of those things easy to overlook. This is actually part of a larger pattern, but in the middle the issue didn't show up with a similar sub-pattern .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which regex engine you're using or how, but regex matchers do not necessarily attempt to match the pattern to the *whole* input or to find the longest match.  Generally, they are satisfied to find *any* match, and if several are possible then which one is matched depends on the engine.  Bearing that that in mind, note that the initial `.2` substring of your input can indeed be matched to the pattern by exercising the pattern's single-digit alternative.

Your second example could, conceivably, match just `0.` rather than the whole string.  The fact that it does match the whole string is a function of the regex engine's implementation, or of how you're using it, or both.

If you want to require that the pattern match the entire input (or else not match at all), then *anchor* it:

```
^(\.(\d|\d\d))$
```

In most regex dialects you will encounter, `^` matches the (zero-width) start of the input or of one line of the input, and, similarly, `$` matches the end.

Comment: As for now I'm only testing with regex101.com